# Python Streamlit, and yfinance issues

Tags: python, pandas, spacy, streamlit, yfinance

I'll just list the two bugs I know as of now, and if you have any recommendations for refactoring my code let me know I'll go ahead and list out the few known issues as of now.

1. yfinance is not appending the `dividendYield` to my dict, I did make sure that their is an actual Dividend Yield for those Symbols.

[image]

2. `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Tag") to str` which I assume is something to do with how it parsing through the xml, and it ran into a tag so I am not able to create the expander, I thought I could solve it with this if  statement, but instead I just don't get any expander at all.

```
with st.expander("Expand for stocks news"):
    for heading in fin_headings:
        if heading == str:
            st.markdown("* " + heading)
        else:
            pass
```

Full code for main.py:

```
import requests
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import streamlit as st
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


st.title("Fire stocks :fire:")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")


def extract_rss(rss_link):
    # Parses xml, and extracts the headings.
    headings = []
    response1 = requests.get(
        "http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/marketpulse/")
    response2 = requests.get(rss_link)
    parse1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.content, features="xml")
    parse2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, features="xml")
    headings1 = parse1.findAll('title')
    headings2 = parse2.findAll('title')
    headings = headings1 + headings2
    return headings


def stock_info(headings):
    # Get the entities from each heading, link it with nasdaq data // if possible, and Extract market data with yfinance.
    stock_dict = {
        'Org': [],
        'Symbol': [],
        'currentPrice': [],
        'dayHigh': [],
        'dayLow': [],
        'forwardPE': [],
        'dividendYield': []
    }
    stocks_df = pd.read_csv("./data/nasdaq_screener_1658383327100.csv")
    for title in headings:
        doc = nlp(title.text)
        for ent in doc.ents:
            try:
                if stocks_df['Name'].str.contains(ent.text).sum():
                    symbol = stocks_df[stocks_df['Name'].str.contains(
                        ent.text)]['Symbol'].values[0]
                    org_name = stocks_df[stocks_df['Name'].str.contains(
                        ent.text)]['Name'].values[0]

                    # Recieve info from yfinance
                    stock_info = yf.Ticker(symbol).info
                    print(symbol)
                    stock_dict['Org'].append(org_name)
                    stock_dict['Symbol'].append(symbol)

                    stock_dict['currentPrice'].append(
                        stock_info['currentPrice'])
                    stock_dict['dayHigh'].append(stock_info['dayHigh'])
                    stock_dict['dayLow'].append(stock_info['dayLow'])
                    stock_dict['forwardPE'].append(stock_info['forwardPE'])
                    stock_dict['dividendYield'].append(
                        stock_info['dividendYield'])
                else:
                    # If name can't be found pass.
                    pass
            except:
                # Don't raise an error.
                pass

    output_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stock_dict, orient='index')
    output_df = output_df.transpose()
    return output_df


# Add input field input field
user_input = st.text_input(
    "Add rss link here", "https://www.investing.com/rss/news.rss")

# Get financial headlines
fin_headings = extract_rss(user_input)

print(fin_headings)
# Output financial info
output_df = stock_info(fin_headings)
output_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, subset='Symbol')
st.dataframe(output_df)

with st.expander("Expand for stocks news"):
    for heading in fin_headings:
        if heading == str:
            st.markdown("* " + heading)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: `fin_headings` is a list of `Tag` objects from Beautiful Soup. You need to extract the text from the tag object first. [See](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in your logic in stock_info function because of which same symbol is getting different values and when you are cleaning the duplicate, based on occurrence of the symbol its retaining the row with first occurrence of symbol.

The below code will solve both of your issues.

```
import requests
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import streamlit as st
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

st.title("Fire stocks :fire:")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def extract_rss(rss_link):
    # Parses xml, and extracts the headings.
    headings = []
    response1 = requests.get(
        "http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/marketpulse/")
    response2 = requests.get(rss_link)
    parse1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.content, features="xml")
    parse2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, features="xml")
    headings1 = parse1.findAll('title')
    headings2 = parse2.findAll('title')
    headings = headings1 + headings2
    return headings

def stock_info(headings):
    stock_info_list = []
    stocks_df = pd.read_csv("./data/nasdaq_screener_1658383327100.csv")
    for title in headings:
        doc = nlp(title.text)
        for ent in doc.ents:
            try:
                if stocks_df['Name'].str.contains(ent.text).sum():
                    symbol = stocks_df[stocks_df['Name'].str.contains(
                        ent.text)]['Symbol'].values[0]
                    org_name = stocks_df[stocks_df['Name'].str.contains(
                        ent.text)]['Name'].values[0]

                    # Recieve info from yfinance
                    print(symbol)
                    stock_info = yf.Ticker(symbol).info

                    stock_info['Org'] = org_name
                    stock_info['Symbol'] = symbol
                    stock_info_list.append(stock_info)
                else:
                    # If name can't be found pass.
                    pass
            except:
                # Don't raise an error.
                pass

    output_df = pd.DataFrame(stock_info_list)
    return output_df

# Add input field input field
user_input = st.text_input(
    "Add rss link here", "https://www.investing.com/rss/news.rss")

# Get financial headlines
fin_headings = extract_rss(user_input)


output_df = stock_info(fin_headings)

output_df = output_df[['Org','Symbol','currentPrice','dayHigh','dayLow','forwardPE','dividendYield']]
output_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, subset='Symbol')
st.dataframe(output_df)


with st.expander("Expand for stocks news"):
    for heading in fin_headings:
        heading = heading.text
        if type(heading) == str:
            st.markdown("* " + heading)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Cool thank you, I know there is still some refactoring I can do, I took out that random else statement, anything else you recommend? Also any reason for not using the dictionary? Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

For issue **#2** the patch code that you posted has a small mistake. Rather than checking if `heading == str`, which does something completely different than you intended and will always be `False`, you want to check if `isinstance(heading, str)`. That way you get `True` if `heading` is a string and `False` if not. However, even then, it should not be a solution as `heading` is not a string. Instead you want to call [`get_text`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) on `heading` to get the actual text part of the parsed object.

```
heading.get_text()
```

More information would be needed to solve issue **#1**. What does `stock_dict` look like before you create the Dataframe out of it? Specifically, what values are in `stock_dict['dividendYield']`? Can you print it and add it to your question?

Also, about the refactoring part. An

```
else:
    pass
```

block does completely nothing and should be deleted. (When the if condition is false nothing happens anyways)